# JSON Array from server get two values

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to programming and pardon my question. I'm currently getting column **officer_name** from my remote server. Parse it to JSON and send to the app. But I want to add another column data **reference** with INT data type and send it with **officer_name** together to App. How can I achieve such thing?

sql query

```
$sql = "select officer_name from user_tbl where user_name like '".$user_name."' and password like '".$password."' and activate = 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$officer_name = $row[0];
$code = "Login_Success";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"officer_name"=>$officer_name));
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Android Java Code for getting JSON**

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                    if (code.equals("Login_Failed"))
                                    {
                                        builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                                        displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                        bundle.putString("officer_name", jsonObject.getString("officer_name"));
                                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
```

As of now I am only getting officer_name from the server. And I want to add a data **reference** column from my database with INT value.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that because you SELECT only OFFICER_NAME and no other column.
When you want to select more just type in (SELECT officer_name, data_u_want2, data_u_need3 FROM etc..)

my scripts that get userdata look usually like this:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];

                                  // SELECT what you want
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"s",$username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, 
                        $userID, 
                        $username, 
                        $password, 
                        $email, 
                        $age, 
                        $realname, 
                        $streetname, 
                        $postcode, 
                        $city,
                        $state);

$response = array();

$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;        
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["realname"] = $realname;
    $response["streetname"] = $streetname;
    $response["postcode"] = $postcode;
    $response["city"] = $city;
    $response["state"] = $state;        
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

you should use prepared statements in the future to prevent sql-injection.

you can change $username to $officer_name or whatever and put your columnts you want to get into the $response